# как создать файл во всех поддиректориях

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell, fish-shell

есть некая структура папок там много папок и под папок,
в гит пустые папки не загружаются и мне в них нужно создать файл,
я пытался это сделать так

```
find MY-DIR -type d -exec echo 'gitdirnoempty' >  .gitdirnoempty {}\;
```

но файл не создался что делать ?

Comment: не понятно при чем тут cp. но `>` следует заключить в кавычки, потому что без них в файл направится вывод find. И кстати не факт что перенаправление так вообще заработает. Тогда стоит для создания файла воспользоваться  touch

Comment: А еще непонятно почему вы в команду пытаетесь подставить путь после имени файла в который собираетесь писать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самое простое:

```
find MY-DIR -type d -exec touch '{}/.gitdirnoempty' \;
```

Также стоит добавить `-empty`, чтобы создавать файлы только в пустых каталогах:

```
find MY-DIR -type d -empty -exec touch '{}/.gitdirnoempty' \;
```

Если хочешь что-то непременно записать в файл, то как-то так:

```
find MY-DIR -type d -exec sh -c 'echo gitdirnoempty >"$0/.gitdirnoempty"' '{}' \;
```

Ошибки в исходном варианте:

- `;` должна быть отдельным аргументом
- вся конструкция с перенаправлением была довольно бессмысленна т.к. она интерпретируется shell'ом и перенаправляет вывод `find` в файл в текущем каталоге.